# How to format output date php

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a small piece of my script when a user logs in that shows their membership expiration date, however it displays the output as `yyyy-mm-dd`. I am assuming this is because of how it is displayed in the sql table.

```
<? echo "Welcome, {$_SESSION['username']}"; ?><p>
<?php

// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("server", "db", "db") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error());

$query =  "SELECT `Date` FROM `USERS` WHERE `username` = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'";
// Retrieve all the data from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())
or die(mysql_error());

// store the record of the "example" table into $row
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

echo "Membership Expiration Date: ".$row['Date'];
?>
```

I have tried putting format commands in

```
".$row['Date'];
```

such as

```
".$row['Date , M d, Y'];
".$row['Date , M-d-Y'];
```

However I am sure that is wrong. I'm reading date formats and conversions however if I need to convert it, I am not sure where to input it. If it needs to be defined before the echo, or if I'm missing something in the

```
".$row['Date'];
```

Still trying, however any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `strtotime` along with `date`:

```
echo "Membership Expiration Date: ". date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['Date']));
```

If `$row['Date']` is already a timestamp, then skip `strtotime`:

```
echo "Membership Expiration Date: ". date("Y-m-d", $row['Date']);
```

For more help, check all the similar questions asked on the column to your right --------------------------->>

Comment: This was it! I was looking into the strtotime function I just didn't know how to write it in the correct syntax. Thank you Aziz. Will accept the correct answer when I can in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

What you will want to do is use the date functions. Here is how you will manipulate your date:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['Date']));
```

This will display a date to the M-d-Y format. If you want more details you can read the [official PHP date documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 0):

You could change the SQL string using the date_format() MySQL function. It should something like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`Date`, ''%m/%d/%y'') AS Date FROM `USERS` WHERE `username` = '
```

That should bring you the date as a formatted string.